# Passing parameters to controller method from route in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I want to pass a parameter from my route to a controller method, to avoid duplication of code. For example, I could have my routes like this

```
Route::get('used-cars',          array('uses' => 
'CarController@indexUsed'));
Route::get('new-cars',           array('uses' => 
'CarController@indexNew'));
Route::get('new-and-used-cars',  array('uses' => 
'CarController@indexNewAndUsed'));
```

and then have specific code for in each method for retrieving that car type. However, I would like to just have one index method in the controller, with a variable passed to it to indicate if it is a new or used car.

For example:

```
Route::get('used-cars',          array('uses' => 
'CarController@index(1)'));
Route::get('new-cars',           array('uses' => 
'CarController@index(2)'));
Route::get('new-and-used-cars',  array('uses' => 
'CarController@index(3)'));
```

In previous versions of Laravel I believe this could be achieved using something like this

```
Route::get('/used-cars', array('as' => 'used-cars', function(){
    return App::make('CarsController')->index(1);
}));
```

However I understand this was removed in Laravel 5.4. When I try it I only get class not found for the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a named parameter (`type`), and restrict that to specific values (`new`, `used`).

```
Route::get('{type}-cars', ['as' => 'cars.new-used', 'uses' => 'CarController@index'])->where('type', 'new|used');
```

Comment: One snag, new-and-used-cars fails as only 'new' was used for the type. Got around it by having a route above that had {type}-and-used-cars. :-)

Comment: Or you could add another type called `all`, unless you’re dead set on `new-and-used`.